# Using .htaccess for dev and prod environment (redirect anything to subfolder)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, jekyll

I'm using Jekyll and I'm on my dev stage where I want to test the whole website on XAMPP. The problem is that Jekyll generates relative URLs showing to the root. But in XAMPP (Apache Webserver) the webpage doesn't work because CSS, JS, images are not in root.

Example of generated HTML:
`<img src="/assets/img/logo.png">`
So Apache is searching *assets/img/* in root, but everything is in a subfolder in dev env.

The URL of the HTML site on my development environment is `http://localhost/k.dev/k.dev/_site/kontakt.php`. There is no problem on production with Apache webserver because the website will be in webroot.

How can I handle this problem for dev and prod environment with .htaccess? Maybe with a system variable? And how can I fix the URLs now?

```
RewriteEngine on

# Development
RewriteCond %{ENV:ENVIRONMENT} = dev
# RewriteRule or Redirect? Add prefix /subfolder/subfolder/ to all links like /page1.html, /page2.html, /assets/, /inc/ etc.
```

Thank you very much.

EDIT:
I created a VirtualHost in XAMPP Apache Webserver. The documentroot is the subfolder now. Thanks to @brombeer.

Comment: Set up an Apache Vhost and point its DocumentRoot to the path

Comment: How is this a programing Question? Why have you tagged it as PHP?

Comment: @user3646958 You should add that as an answer (and later accept it), rather than edit your question with the answer. Otherwise, your question still looks "unanswered".